# Traverse materialized path hierarchy for children nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have a sorted list of materialized hierarchy paths:

```
paths = ['10001', '1000100001', '100010000100001', '100010000100002', '1000100002', '100010000200001', '100010000200002']
```

I am getting the immediate children paths (nodes) for each non leaf node.

```py
steplen = 5 # size of each hierarchy step
max_depth = len(max(paths, key=len)) // steplen
def _traverse_hierarchy(parent='', idx=0) -> Tuple[int, List[str]]:
    children_paths_for_parent = []
    while idx < len(paths) and paths[idx].startswith(parent):
        path = paths[idx]
        if len(path) == len(parent) + steplen: # direct report
            children_paths_for_parent.append(path)

        idx += 1
        if len(path) // steplen != max_depth: # not leaf node
            new_idx, children_paths = _traverse_hierarchy(parent=path, idx=idx)
            print(f'Direct Reports for {path}', children_paths)
            idx = new_idx

    return idx, children_paths_for_parent
```

I'm not concerned about getting a stack overflow error (the hierarchy won't be too deep).

How can I improve/optimize this code?

Comment: `parent_dr_paths` and `max_depth` are NOT defined in your code. Post an extended, valid context